# How to add class to options within a CheckboxSelectMultiple displayed with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm wanting to add bootstrap classes to the options of a CheckboxSelectMultiple displayed with crispy forms. I know how to add a class to the whole CheckboxSelectMultiple div, but not to each of the elements within it (I'm wanting to give each a class of col-3 so they align next to each other in a neat grid).

I'm displaying the form (the form also has many other fields) with:

```
{% crispy form form.helper %}
```

and this is the form.py

```
TOPICS = (
        ('ANI', 'Animals'),
        ('ART', 'Art'),
        ('COM', 'Communication'),
        ('CRI', 'Crime'),
        ('CUL', 'Culture/Society'),
    )

topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TOPICS, required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for`inlinecheckboxes`. If you want only so many items on each row you can over ride the inlinecheckbox template with col-3 (or col-md-3?).

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to an inlinecheckbox. I have read the information on that site about overriding templates before but can't get my head around it. I understand that within Layout I should specify the field then template='new_template', but I don't know where to create that template file or what should be in it? Should it just be like a css file? If so, I am still unsure how to change the class of the items within the inlinecheckbox rather than the whole field. Thank you.